# Downloading QGIS to Samsung Galaxy 7s?

Tags: qgis, qgis-android

I'm trying to download the QGIS to my phone from the the google play with no success.

Any ideas why not or can I download it from a different place?

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS is a desktop application, you can't install it on a smartphone. But you can use QField which is an Android app designed to open QGIS projects, you can download it from the Play Store or from GitHub (https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases).

Comment: Actually, you can: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qgis.qgis&hl=de

Comment: You're right, but it's unusable on a smartphone (too small screen) and very buggy. I should have said that instead of "can't install" ;-)